# Most efficient way to find the collection of all ids in a collection of entities

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons

I have an entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    private long id;    
    private String data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

and a collection of entities:

```
Collection<Entity> entities= ...
```

What is the most efficient way to find the `Collection<Long>` of all the ids in `entities`?

Comment: Please clarify, by "most efficient", do you mean "fastest" or "shortest"?

Comment: @Boann since I assume all ways would iterate over the collection... in this case I mean "shortest"

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
class Entity {
    final long id;
    final String data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    Entity(long id, String data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you can write

```
Collection<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(new Entity(1, "one"), 
                  new Entity(11, "eleven"), new Entity(100, "one hundred"));
// get a collection of all the ids.
List<Long> ids = entities.stream()
                         .map(Entity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(ids);
```

prints

```
[1, 10, 100]
```

As you can imagine this is rather ugly in Java 7 or less.  Note the `Entity.getId` when applied to map() means call this method on each element.

Now, the real interesting part is you can do this.

```
List<Long> ids = entities.parallelStream()
                         .map(Entity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In *most cases* using a parallel stream will hurt performance, but it makes trying it and seeing amazingly easy (possibly too easy ;)

---

The most efficient way is to have, or build a Map.

```
Map<Long, Entity> entitiesMap = ...
// get all ids
Collection<Long> addIds = entitiesMap.keySet();

// look up entities by id.
List<Long> ids = ...
List<Entity> matching = new ArrayList<>();
for(Long id: ids)
    matching.add(entitiesMap.get(id));
```

Comment: Of course, but is there a utility that could do this for me in `Guava` or `Apache Commons`?

Comment: @rapt without closures it would be more code to use a library than to just write a simple loop.  Can you use Java 8?

Comment: In that case forget Guava and Apache Commons and just use streams, it is much easier.  Do you have a getter for Id as that would help.

Comment: @rapt I have updated my answer.  if you are using Java 8, you really want to get you head around closures.

Comment: and BTW, what would it look like in Java 7? I thought closures were introduced only starting at Java 8?

Comment: @rapt In Java 7 you would use a loop. It is only due to Java 8's syntactic sugar that it even makes some sense. Note: the loop is still shorter code.

Comment: Equivalent is  .map(e -> e.getId()).collect(..)

Comment: @Míra This is slightly shorter due to the length of the class name. I meant if you turned all the variables/class into one letter and counted the symbols involved, the loop would be shorter in terms of symbol complexity.

Comment: Since Java 16 there is now a better variant to produce an unmodifiable list directly from a stream: Stream.toList() instead of Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 5):

Most efficient? Basically just iterate and add to the list. You have to look at each item.

```
Collection<Long> ids = new LinkedList<Long>();
for (Entity e : entities) {
    ids.add(e.id);
}
```

Or, if you can use Java 1.8, you can do something like:

```
entities.forEach((e) -> ids.add(e.id));
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use an `ArrayList` and specify its size (i.e. `entities.size()`).

Comment: `entities.forEach((e) -> ids.add(e))` is the same as `ids.addAll(entries)`;

Comment: Sorry i meant ids.add(e.id)

Answer (score 3):

You won't get anything shorter than:

```
Collection<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (Entity e : entities) ids.add(e.getId());
```

> I assume all ways would iterate over the collection

Not necessarily. This creates a collection that is directly backed by the underlying entities collection (future changes to the entities collection appear in the ids collection):

```
Collection<Long> ids = new AbstractCollection<Long>() {
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return entities.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Long> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Long>() {
            private Iterator<Entity> base = entities.iterator();
            @Override public boolean hasNext() { return base.hasNext(); }
            @Override public Long next() { return base.next().getId(); }
            @Override public void remove() { base.remove(); }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is necessarily the most efficient, but for pre-Java 8, I've become fond of using property interfaces as described here: http://blog.cgdecker.com/2010/06/property-interfaces-and-guava.html

As described in the blog post, you would have a simple interface named something like HasId:

```
public interface HasId {
    long getId();
}
```

Your Entity class would look like this:

```
public class Entity implements HasId {
    private long id;    
    private String data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

and you would have a simple Function like this somewhere:

```
public class ToId implements Function<HasId, Long> {
    public Long apply(HasId hasId) {
        return hasId.getId();
    }
}
```

Finally, to make use of it:

```
Collection<Long> ids = Collections2.transform(entities, new ToId());
```

This is excessive if you only need it for one thing, but if you have a ton of objects that can sanely implement HasId or other such interfaces, I find it very enjoyable to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead converting list to stream and then back to list

I will recommend  below

Collection ids = new LinkedList();
entities.forEach((e) -> ids.add(e.id));

Answer (score 0):

We can Also Try this approach

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
entities.Stream().map(entity->ids.add(entity.getId()));
```

Comment: You are replying to an old question which already has an accepted answer.